# Which is better to use frequently in objects: Vector2f or 2 floats

Tags: java, object, memory, vector, floating-point

I am currently working on some code for my GUI elements and while working on the code for detecting if the mouse is within the element I had a thought about efficiency, not only now but in the future.  Currently I am using Vector2f for both dimensions and position due to the ease of passing them in and out of functions with calls to functions such as getDimensions which just returns the Vector2f and so on.  My question though is whether I am being wasteful with my use of Vectors in general and Vector2f specifically.  Is it better to have two floats within my objects for x and y and two for width and height or to have the two vectors, one for position and one for dimensions.

The main worry is that creating the Vector objects takes up more space than just using the primitive floats.  I have looked at the source of the Vector2f and 3f classes for ideas and they seem to be very light weight but seeing as I know very little about how much memory different objects take up and how it is all determined that I would ask those who could much easier understand the problem at hand.

Thank you in advance for any and all answers!

Comment: Have you tried any sort of measurement?

Comment: Let's assume you have 1000 GUI elements (which is already a lot), and each has 2 Vector2f instances. An object has 8 bytes of overhead. That means a total of 1000 * 2 * 8 bytes of overhead. 16 KBs of memory is absolutely nothing.

Comment: I've never attempted any sort of measurement and would have no idea how to go about it 358 but if I did it would have been the first thing I would have done so thanks!  And JB thank you for the info.  The stuff like overhead is the stuff that I didn't know and the reason I asked here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answer is: stick to objects, as they make your code readable.

If you really need to save memory, read [An overview of memory saving techniques in Java
(by Mikhail Vorontsov)](http://java-performance.info/overview-of-memory-saving-techniques-java/). Arrays consume 12 bytes plus their length multiplied by their element size . Wrappers occupy 12 bytes extra to the underlying type.

In your case:

- Vector2f: 16 bytes
- float[2]: 16 bytes
- 2 floats: 8 bytes

Comment: Thank you very much for the link as well as the information, especially the tip to stick to objects.  Good to know that it wont make to large of a difference.